# ASP.NET MVC routing and areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-areas

I am messing around with ASP.NET MVC 2 Preview 2 and am trying to figure out how routing works with areas and such.  In a single project implementation of areas, I want an area named "admin".

I am trying to be able to have urls like this:

```
(root)/admin/apples/search
(root)/admin/apples/edit/3
(root)/admin/apples/add
(root)/admin/oranges/search
(root)/admin/oranges/edit/5
(root)/admin/oranges/add
(root)/admin
```

I have the area created.  I have the controllers created with their respective views, but it is the routing that I can't seem to get.  Any advice as to how I would achieve such routing?

I am sure this may be extremely simple for some, but I haven't had too much luck in finding examples that go beyond the basic stuff.

Thanks!

**Addition to the Question (10/25/2009)**
I am basically asking what routes and in what order would I set up in the Area's AreaRegistration class?  I have done everything mentioned so far, but with no results.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Register areas in single project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461420%28VS.100%29.aspx#registering_area_routes)

You have to add routes.cs file to the admin area folder.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcAreasSingleProject.Areas.Admin
{
    public class Routes : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get { return "admin"; }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "admin_default",
                "admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Admin", action = "Edit", id = "" }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/07/31/single-project-areas.aspx

```
routes.MapAreaRoute("Forums", 
        "admin_area", 
        "admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
        new { controller = "apples", action = "search", id = "" }, 
        new string[] { "Project.Areas.Admin.Controllers" });
```

Comment: That is for ASP.NET MVC 2 Preview 1 - I am working on Preview 2 which includes out of the box implementation of areas in a single project.  RouteCollection doesn't even have a MapAreaRoute method in Preview 2.